# python - the index of the item where the next 10 items starts repeating

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing some simple modelling with Monte Carlo method. Basically I want to find the point where the value converges. My data structure is a list l. for simplicity,

```
l = range(10) + [1] * 10
```

so `l[10:10 + 10] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

How do I automatically find the index (in this case 10) where the next 10 items in the list start repeating the same value (that is the point where the values converge).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One that works on iterables:

```
def find_convergence(iterable, count):
    current_count = 0
    last = None

    for i, x in enumerate(iterable):
        if x == last:
            current_count += 1

            if current_count == count:
                return i - count + 1
        else:
            last = x
            current_count = 1
```

This may be a little verbose, but it’s linear time on the length of the iterable and constant-space.

Comment: I don't know. It works exactly the way I want it and I'm very grateful. But I do not have enough points to upvote. I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an O(n) algorithm for each query using dynamic programming. Depending on how your program updates this list and what values it will hold, there may be an O(log n) update/query algorithm instead of this, e.g., a Fenwick tree.

```
l = range(10) + [1]*10
dp, ans = [1 for i in l], []
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    if l[i] == l[i - 1]:
        dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + 1
    if dp[i] >= 10:
        ans.append(i - 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = range(10) + [1]*10
>>> for i in range(len(L)-10+1):
...     if len(set(L[i:i+10])) == 1:
...         print i
... 
10
```

Also, there's an itertools recipe for it

```
import itertools
L = range(10) + [1]*10
comp = itertools.groupby(L)
i = 0
for _k,run in comp:
    run = list(run)
    if len(run) == 10:
        print i
    i += len(run)
```

Comment: Ah, that `groupby` is clever! I think you might need to adjust `i` by the previous counts, though.

Comment: @minitech: `previous counts`?

Comment: Won’t `i` be the index of the group, not the start of the group in the original list?

Comment: Yes. OP wants the index, so I had to track it with enumerate

Comment: Oh the groupby is really nice. I don't have to restrict to a specific number in this way. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it’s the index of the group compared to the other groups, not compared to the other items. (Also, you shouldn’t have to call `list(run)` to use `len(run)`.)

Comment: @minitech: I have to listify in python2 to get `len`, since `'itertools.groupby' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`